# Changet POST to Delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I Changed a http method POST to DELETE and when i click a button nothing happens.

what i have but works

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  //do something
});
```

what i want

```
router.delete('/', function(req, res) {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: Unless that button is linked up via DELETE this route won't engage. You can't use GET.

Comment: Can you post the code of the button?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to remember when defining your server side routes is that even though two route definitions may have the same path but different HTTP verbs, they are not treated as the same by the RESTful API infrastructure. It is essentially like defining two completely separate functions in a class. The `POST` route will only ever be called if a `POST` request is sent to the applicable route, while the `DELETE` route will only ever be called if a `DELETE` request is sent to the applicable route. The execution of those two different route definitions is completely dependent on the HTTP verb that is specified in the HTTP request object that is sent to your API. You can read about all of the different HTTP request methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Without being able to see the code for your button, all I can say is that in order to fix your broken code, you need to make sure that your HTTP request that is being sent to the server is specifying a `DELETE` HTTP verb instead of the original `POST` HTTP verb that your code was originally specifying when your code initially worked.